# Can't you put the texture in the 2d grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I'm going to draw a person. I want to put a pattern in the clothes he's wearing.

The picture above is textured in Matterial, but there is no response

So I touched it, but I don't know how to put in the pattern. I can't find it on YouTube

Is there any way to put it in after clipping like a clip studio?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Export to grease pencil from uv texture

Then, join the object on the bottom layer.[image]

Then, position the image layer at the most extreme, turn on the mask, and enter the layer below in the mask.